# Borel functional calculus and multiplication operator

Tags: functional-analysis, spectral-theory

Let $A_f$ be the multiplication operator in $L^2(\mathbb R)$ with the function $f$. If $g$ is a bounded Borel function on $\mathbb R$, why is $g(A_f)$ defined by the functional calculus the multiplication operator $A_{g \circ f}$ of multiplication with $g \circ f$?

For polynomials $g$ this is clear. And since polynomials are dense in the continuous functions we get it for continuous $g$. How do i get the result for characteristic and (thus again by limit argument) for bounded Borel functions? Do i need to invoke the Lusin theorem or is there another ('more elementary') argument?

Comment: Somehow you have to transition from continuous functions to bounded Borel functions, and this transition must be done in the strong operator topology, instead of the uniform operator topology. You could show the result you want for intervals and then argue that it holds for the sigma algebra generated by the intervals.

Comment: Actually, i realized that Stone Weierstrass needs compactness of the domain. How can one argue that one even has the result for continuous functions? Do i have to start from the outset from compact intervals. Also i dont know how to do the step from continuous to bounded Borel functions.

Comment: Look at $(p(A_f)g,h)$ for polynomials $p$ and compactly supported functions $g$, $h$.